# vba excel loop_ show iteration number while running (not progress bar)

Tags: vba, loops, excel, progress

I have 250.000 lines and I wanted to erase all lines that have a 0 in col AR. This takes too much time using a filter and deleting only visible cells, so I wrote a code. The thing is that I would like to see the progress, but not adding a form, only the number of iteration would be enough.

Is there a way to show the iteration number while running the loop?

My code is:

```
Sub delrow()

Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("bners")
LR3 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i3 = 3 To LR3
    a = Sheets("bners").Range("AR" & i3).Value
    If a = 0 Then
    Rows(i3).Delete
    Else
    End If
Next i3
End With

Application.calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at debugging:http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: You could try re-introduce the filter with code, i.e. mark each row that will be delete and apply filter at the end to remove them all at once

Comment: You may want to double check the you don't have to sorround the 0 with qoutes.  During my testing it was deleting lines that are null/empty but if I surround it with qoutes then it actually skips the lines until "0"

Comment: Good point, but anyway I don't have empty cells before the end of the range and it goes until that line. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use

```
    count = 0
    For....
      'your code
       count = count + 1
       Application.StatusBar = Count
    next
```

Displays at the bottom status bar.  Simple and to me does not weigh heavy.

Answer (score 4):

Use StatusBar and it will shown on the Statusbar (Duh):

```
Application.StatusBar = "Current iteration: " & i3
```

Comment: I like  your example better for using OPs i3

Comment: @mrbungle Thanks and we hope Gaby doesn't meant StatusBar while saying "no Progress bar" in the question

Comment: I would change to show current row and total count, that way the user can have an idea of how long it will take. Like this: `Application.StatusBar = "Current iteration: " & i3 & " of " & LR3`

Answer (score 0):

You could add this inside your loop:

```
 Range("A1") = i3
```

This would set the top left cell to the number to the current iteration, though it wont be very smooth.

Comment: yep, thanks. yet i have another problem. to go through 1000 lines takes 1 minute, so 250.000 lines are 250 minutes so it's more than 4 hours. How can I do this more efficiently? I will post another question.

Comment: I will commend on your question section